# Make TortoiseSVN treat a file as not changed

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a file which I modified and I don't want these changes to be committed. How do I get TortoiseSVN ignore this file during commits? However if I make changes after that point, I want the file not to be ignored anymore.

Answer (score 5):

You prevent the changes from being committed by deselecting the checkbox for that file in the TortoiseSVN commit dialog.

Comment: Was looking for another way than doing this every time. Basically do not show up in that list and force svn to think it has NOT been modified

Comment: @Tony_Henrich I think you'll need to write a script or program for this. Your requirement sounds fairly exotic. Care to elaborate what you need this for? Maybe somebody has a workaround idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the file to the special changelist **ignore-on-commit**. Once you have done that you no longer have to deselect the file every time you open the commit dialog.

Once you really want to commit the changes made to that file, you can simply select (check) it in the commit dialog and it will be committed.

Details about this feature are [described here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-commit.html#tsvn-dug-commit-ignore).

Comment: This is a nice idea, will +1 tomorrow when I have votes. However, it doesn't automate the OP's second requirement - getting into SVN's scope again if changes have been made after committing. That sounds pretty much impossible to achieve without custom programming / scripting.

Comment: If you want to commit the file later again, just either remove it from the ignore-on-commit changelist, or manually check it for commit.